# WebExtension: Security implications of modifying cookies of third-party website to SameSite=None + Secure

Tags: security, cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, samesite

First, I apologize that this is not strictly a coding, algorithm or language question.

I'm trying to create an extension that allows a website (let's call this web-A) to embed a small set of other websites within it. These other websites, (let's call this web-E) employ authentication, and store their cookies with `SameSite=Lax`. This causes users to never be logged in, or be able to log in when website E is embedded within A.

The WebExtension APIs allow me to modify cookies of all websites. Modifying cookies of web-E to have `SameSite=None` and adding `Secure` appears to solve this issue. However, I'm not sure about the security implications of doing this.

Additionally, it appears that modifying these cookies of web-E is a global change, and would affect the way in which these cookies are accessible on all websites.

What are the security implications of modifying cookies from `SameSite=Lax` to `Samesite=None`+`Secure`? Is it safe to perform this operation via a browser extension that will be used by other users?

Comment: Not being an expert on cookies I suggest an alternative approach: you can intercept the network requests inside those frames only using chrome.webRequest API and patch the cookie headers both in the request and response just inside those iframes. To limit observation use `tabId` (in background script it'll be `-1`) and other [filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription) available for webRequest listeners, just don't forget to specify 'extraHeaders'.

Comment: I believe you cannot modify cookie headers in the response. I haven't tried request yet

Comment: You certainly can.

Comment: chrome.webRequest allows you to modify Cookie and Set-Cookie if you specify 'extraHeaders' in opt_extraInfoSpec. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest